# Handling a TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when switching from fetching a single item to fetching a list

Tags: python, json, list, error-handling, typeerror

I am trying to fetch data from a JSON endpoint. It doesn't work anymore now that I have switched from fetching just one data value `coin['id']` to fetching multiple ones. I have this code:

```
class Checker:
    def __init__(self, urls, wait_time):
        self.wait_time = wait_time
        self.urls = urls
        self.coins = self.get_coins()
        self.main_loop()
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_data(url):
        url = requests.get(url)
        text = url.text
        data = json.loads(text)
        coins = [[coin['symbol'], coin['name'], coin['market_cap'], coin['market_cap_rank']] for coin in data]
        return coins
    
    def get_coins(self):
        coins = set()
        for url in self.urls:
            coins.update(Checker.get_data(url))
        return coins

    def check_new_coins(self):
        new_coins = self.get_coins()
        
        coins_diff = list(new_coins.difference(self.coins))
        coins_out = list((self.coins).difference(new_coins))
        
        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
        
        if len(coins_diff) > 0:
            # print(current_time, coins_diff)
            bot_message = f'New coins alert at {current_time} \n'
            for in_coin in coins_diff:
                bot_message += f'NAME:{in_coin[1]} SYMBOL:{in_coin[0]} MARKET CAP: {in_coin[2]} MARKET RANK:{in_coin[3]}\n'
            print(bot_message)
        else:
            pass
        
        self.coins = new_coins
    
    def main_loop(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(self.wait_time)
            self.check_new_coins()
```

When I was initially fetching just one data point from the JSON object using
`coins = [coin['id'] for coin in data]` in the `get_data()` method, it was working just fine. But now I want to fetch 4 data points so I switched to fetching a list using `coins = [[coin['symbol'], coin['name'], coin['market_cap'], coin['market_cap_rank']] for coin in data]`. That is when the `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` error started coming up with the following trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\discord\bot2.py", line 62, in <module>
    Checker(urls, 300)
  File "C:\discord\bot2.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.coins = self.get_coins()
  File "C:\discord\bot2.py", line 26, in get_coins
    coins.update(Checker.get_data(url))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How can I resolve this so that instead of initially printing just the `coin['id']`, I can also print the `coin['name'],coin['market_cap'], coin['market_cap_rank']`?

The JSON endpoint is an object where each item in the list has the following structure:

```
{
    "id": "bitcoin",
    "symbol": "btc",
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "image": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1547033579",
    "current_price": 21636,
    "market_cap": 411087658127,
    "market_cap_rank": 1,
    "fully_diluted_valuation": 452613028369,
    "total_volume": 27595965142,
    "high_24h": 21568,
    "low_24h": 19931.52,
    "price_change_24h": 837.49,
    "price_change_percentage_24h": 4.02661,
    "market_cap_change_24h": 15476001610,
    "market_cap_change_percentage_24h": 3.91192,
    "circulating_supply": 19073337,
    "total_supply": 21000000,
    "max_supply": 21000000,
    "ath": 69045,
    "ath_change_percentage": -68.79379,
    "ath_date": "2021-11-10T14:24:11.849Z",
    "atl": 67.81,
    "atl_change_percentage": 31674.91619,
    "atl_date": "2013-07-06T00:00:00.000Z",
    "roi": null,
    "last_updated": "2022-06-21T14:49:06.386Z"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`get_data()` returns a `list`, and `coins.update(Checker.get_data(url))` tries to put that `list` in a `set`. But `set` items need to be *hashable*, and `list`s are not. If you return a `tuple` instead of a `list` everything will be ok.

To see the difference just try

```
x = set([[1,2]]) #error
```

versus

```
x = set(([1,2])) #ok
```

Comment: This helps get rid of the error but i really don't understand what is going on anymore. It has fundamentally changed the logic of my script further down.
As you can see, I am fetching a JSON list from an endpoint and different intervals and I only want the difference in the lists of coins. When i run this with the tuple, it now spits all the coins, not the difference.